# Why does Apple Software Update think that I have iTunes installed, even though I don't?

Tags: windows, itunes, software-update

I have a Windows PC. Somehow, Apple Software Update thinks that I have iTunes installed and offers me updates for it. However, I have never installed iTunes on this PC. I have a couple questions:

1. How does Apple Software Update come to think that I have iTunes installed?
2. Is there a way to tell it that iTunes is in fact not installed on this PC?
3. If I do install an iTunes update through Apple Software Update, will it properly install iTunes on my PC?

Oh, and I acquired Apple Software Update by installing the Bonjour Printer Service to interface Virtual DJ with my iPad.

Comment: iPad (iPhone, iPod) requires iTunes to transfer files to and from. Maybe that's where you got iTunes. I think you can check if iTunes is installed by going to `%programfiles%` and checking for the iTunes folder.

Comment: @Doktoro No iTunes folder exists in both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating Apple Software Update. After that, iTunes properly shows up in the New Software list, which is where it should have been the whole time.

Comment: haha! More broken Apple Software. I'm convinced they don't have a QA process. Too much crap gets through that should be caught.